# Unable to apply cert-manager free certificate from letsencrypt in kube

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I'm using kubernetes to host my app. I want automatically generate and renew lets-encrypt certificates using [cert-manager]
My project is open-source and all kubernetes configs are publicly available [here](https://github.com/akoidan/pychat/tree/nestjs/kubernetes). The domain I'm requesting a certificate is [pychat.org](https://pychat.org/#/auth/sign-in) and is managing my [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/). Kubernetes is set up already, the domain is pointing to the load-balancer ip address and returns index.html correctly.

So I'm following the guide:

1. Installing cert-manager CRD and cert-manager worker itself

```sh
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.8.0/cert-manager.yaml
helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io
helm repo update
helm template cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager --namespace cert-manager --version v1.8.0| kubectl apply -f -
```

2. Defining cloudflare-api key in `cf-secret.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: cloudflare-api-token-secret
type: Opaque
stringData:
  api-token: cf-token-copied-from-api
```

Defining issues and certificate in [cert-manager.yaml](https://github.com/akoidan/pychat/blob/nestjs/kubernetes/cert-manager.yaml):

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    email: deathangel908@gmail.com
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
    - dns01:
        cloudflare:
          email: deathangel908@gmail.com
          apiTokenSecretRef:
            name: cloudflare-api-token-secret
            key: api-token
---

apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: pychat-domain
  namespace: pychat
spec:
  secretName: pychat-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod

  duration: 2160h # 90d
  renewBefore: 720h # 30d before SSL will expire, renew it
  dnsNames:
    - "pychat.org"
    - "*.pychat.org"
```

3 .If I check the certificate, it seems like generated correctly:

```sh
kubectl get secret pychat-tls -n default -o yaml

apiVersion: v1
data:
  tls.crt: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiB...
  tls.key: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBSU0E...
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/alt-names: '*.pychat.org,pychat.org'
    cert-manager.io/certificate-name: pychat-domain
    cert-manager.io/common-name: pychat.org
    cert-manager.io/ip-sans: ""
    cert-manager.io/issuer-group: ""
    cert-manager.io/issuer-kind: Issuer
    cert-manager.io/issuer-name: letsencrypt-prod
    cert-manager.io/uri-sans: ""
  creationTimestamp: "2022-05-21T22:44:22Z"
  name: pychat-tls
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1800"
  uid: f38c228b-b3a6-4649-aaf6-d9727685569c
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

```sh
echo 'tls.crt...LS0tLS1CRUdJTiB' |base64 -d > lol.cert
openssl x509 -in ./lol.cert  -noout -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            04:b4:24:ae:61:c9:24:b6:50:5d:c2:50:0c:28:0f:c1:d5:17
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
        Validity
            Not Before: May 21 21:46:14 2022 GMT
            Not After : Aug 19 21:46:13 2022 GMT
        Subject: CN = pychat.org
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:c7:7f:08:....
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                38:41:8D:F9:5A...
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:14:2E:B3..

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://r3.o.lencr.org
                CA Issuers - URI:http://r3.i.lencr.org/

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:*.pychat.org, DNS:pychat.org
            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.44947.1.1.1
                  CPS: http://cps.letsencrypt.org

            CT Precertificate SCTs: 
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : 46:A5:55:..
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:45:02:21:00:...
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : 6F:53:76:A...
                    Timestamp : May 21 22:46:14.722 2022 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:46:02:...
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         6b:21:da:3a:ea:d8:...
```

4. If I check ingress, it shows this:

```sh
: kubectl describe ingress ingress
Name:             ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        pychat
Address:          194.195.247.104
Default backend:  frontend-service:80 (10.2.0.15:80)
TLS:
  pychat-tls terminates pychat.org
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  pychat.org  
              /api   backend-service:8888 (10.2.0.16:8888,10.2.0.19:8888)
              /ws    backend-service:8888 (10.2.0.16:8888,10.2.0.19:8888)
              /      frontend-service:80 (10.2.0.15:80)
Annotations:  cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-prod
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age                From                       Message
  ----    ------             ----               ----                       -------
  Normal  CreateCertificate  15m                cert-manager-ingress-shim  Successfully created Certificate "pychat-tls"
  Normal  Sync               15m (x2 over 15m)  nginx-ingress-controller   Scheduled for sync
```

5. But If I make a request, it returns self-signed kube default certificate:

```sh
: curl -vk https://pychat.org/ 2>&1 | grep -e subject: -e issuer:
*  subject: O=Acme Co; CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
*  issuer: O=Acme Co; CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
```

The server is hosted on [Linode](https://www.linode.com/) and uses its load balancer if it matters:

```sh
   helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
   helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
   helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

The [ingress.yaml](https://github.com/akoidan/pychat/blob/nestjs/kubernetes/ingress.yaml) configuration looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
  name: ingress
  namespace: pychat
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - pychat.org
    secretName: pychat-tls
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: frontend-service
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
  - host: pychat.org
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend-service
            port:
              number: 8888
      - path: /ws
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend-service
            port:
              number: 8888
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, the guides just don't tell you much about if:

All the resources you create should be in the same namespace as your server. secret `cloud-flare-api-token-secret`, `lets-encrypt-prod` issuer, `pychat-domain` certificate, all of these things should have metadata -> namespace of your server, rather than cert-manager or default one.

Further tip: to debug this issue, I took a look at pods logs:

- `kubectl get all -n cert-manager`
- `kubectl logs pod/cert-manager-id-from-top -n cert-manager`